# Problems with nested loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined, nested-loops

I'm trying to do a nested loop in javascript, it's my first time doing this kind of things and i have a lot of doubts :(!

I need to get the times a variable is printed or used into a loop, and the first thing that passed through my mind was using .length... And I thought it worked... But it did not, or I don't know if it did.

When i used the length method, i get this in the console: [Console Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNQ8f.jpg)

That's the value that i need, but i don't know if I can work with it, i don't even know the value's name and it appears like "undefined" :(!

And i just can't use a console.log on the variable out of the loop because it returns just the last value on it, and not specifically the number of times this is printed on.

If you have more doubts, take a look of my code, maybe it can clarify you guys.

```
function calculatingDays(day, month, year, current_day, current_month, current_year, final_day, callback){

for (k = year; k <= (year + 1); k++){

    for (i = current_month; i <= 12; i++){ 

        for (j = current_day; j <= final_day; j++) {

            console.log(j.length)
            if (j === day && i === month) {break}
        }

    final_day = new Date(year, i, 0);
    final_day = final_day.getDate();
    current_day = 1;
    if (j === day && i === month) {break}

    }

if (j === day && i === month) {break}
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something that can hold the count of times something has occurred. This can best be done by a variable that you can increment. What does this look like?

```
var counter = 0;
// later on when you find you need to increment the counter
counter = counter + 1;
```

Then after you're done looping you can do `console.log(counter)`. In your code you want the `var counter = 0` to occur right above the first `for` loop. Where you are currently doing `console.log(j.length)` is where you increment the counter. Then choose a spot outside of the loop that you want to print it. You have several loops and I'm not sure when you want to print the counter.

Comment: or `counter += 1;`